# How to handle Post value of Dynamic Multidimensional input name (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, multidimensional-array

I have a form that has several sections, each section has several steps. Each step has a minimum of one checkbox, maximum two, and could have a comments text area.

I am loading the entire form (questions) from the DB, and I have created a loop to do that. I also am naming the input field "name" value while passing through the loop as follows:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="section_<?php echo $section_id; ?>[<?php echo $step_numb; ?>][anso]" id="anso-check-<?php echo str_replace(".","-",$section_id)."-" .$step_numb; ?>" required="required">

 <input type="checkbox" name="section_<?php echo $section_id; ?>[<?php echo $step_numb; ?>][anst]" id="anst-check-<?php echo str_replace(".","-",$section_id)."-" .$step_numb; ?>" required="required">

<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)"  name="section_<?php echo $section_id; ?>[<?php echo $step_numb; ?>][com]"></textarea>
```

So basically it will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="section_5[1][anso]" id="anso-check-5-1" required="required">

<input type="checkbox" name="section_5[1][anst]" id="anst-check-5-1" required="required" checked="checked">

<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" name="section_5[1][com]"></textarea>
```

- anso , anst, and com are constant.

I am trying to catch the POST of the form with this:

```
$answer_sections        = array ();  // anso , anst , com

$section_count          = 1; // set to one to handle just thefirst section for testing.
$answer_section_index       = 0;
$section_index          = 5;

    while($section_count > 0){
        $answer_sections[$answer_section_index] = isset($_POST['section_'.$section_index]) ? $_POST['section_'.$section_index] : '';

        $section_index++;
        $answer_section_index++;
        $section_count--;
    }
```

I am expecting $answer_sections[0] to be an array,that has all the steps and their answers. However if i do sizeof($answer_sections[0]), I get a:

PHP Warning:  sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Which this is the first of many errors I am receiving.

Am I using the multidimensional array wrongs? I think I understood that as long as you have the same input name, which in this case is "section_1", then it will be handeled as an array in PHP.

The dump is this:

```
    array(11) { 
            [1]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [2]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [3]=> array(2) {
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [4]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [5]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [6]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [7]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [8]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [9]=> array(2) {
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [10]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } [11]=> array(2) { 
                  ["anso"]=> string(2) "on" ["com"]=> string(0) "" 
             } 
   } 
Array ( [1] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [2] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [3] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [4] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [5] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [6] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [7] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [8] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [9] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [10] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) [11] => Array ( [anso] => on [com] => ) )
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: can you use `var_dump` on $_POST to check if the structure is correct ?

Comment: @MacBooc I get : string(0) ""

Comment: Then you form isn't right, it's not about the php but the HTML part

Comment: I forgot that I start my sections from #5, so updating the #section_index to 5.

Comment: updated with var_dump

Comment: then it should look like `$answer_sections[$answer_section_index] = $_POST['section_'.$section_index][$id] ??  '';` where `$id` is `$step_numb` in your form

Comment: Shouldn't sizeof($answer_sections[$answer_section_index]) tell me the number of steps in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I had it was correct. I had a few syntax errors that needed fixing.